# Json type mismatch

Tags: java, android, json

my json data

```
 {"status":"true","c_id":"72","u_name":"navneet","dob":"2015-01-12","description":"login sucessful"}
```

code for parsing json data

```
try {
    Log.d("oooooooooooo",registerResponse);
    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(registerResponse);
    Log.d("", "responseObjectresponseObject" + responseObject);
    Status = responseObject.getString("status");
    Log.d("", "StatusStatusStatus" + Status);
    res_Desp = responseObject.getString("description");
    Log.d("", "Status_DespStatus_DespStatus_Desp" + res_Desp);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("zxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Error parsing response of change password web service - "
    + t.getMessage());
    t.printStackTrace();
    // return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

errors are:

```
01-13 11:07:02.049  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat D/oooooooooooo﹕ <script> function     abc(){if(window.location.href=="http://corouter.com/res/kidschat/login.php"){ window.location.assign('http://corouter.com/res/kidschat/login.php?username=&password='); }}</script><body onload="abc()"></body> {"status":"true","c_id":"72","u_name":"navneet","dob":"2015-01-12","description":"login sucessful"}
01-13 11:07:02.049  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat E/zxxxxxxxxxx﹕ Error parsing response of change password web service - Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-13 11:07:02.049  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at com.example.welcome.kids_chat.Login_Screen$loadslashscreenTask1.doInBackground(Login_Screen.java:162)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at com.example.welcome.kids_chat.Login_Screen$loadslashscreenTask1.doInBackground(Login_Screen.java:80)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-13 11:07:02.059  11363-11490/com.example.welcome.kids_chat W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-13 11:07:02.079  11363-11363/com.example.welcome.kids_chat D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
```

Comment: As in log `registerResponse` is not valid json string

Comment: as per your logcat show '</script><body onload="abc()"></body>' comes with your response and this is not a valid format..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Your parsing seems ok, But check registerResponse value whether it is valid string or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registerResponse is not having the value you specified above as JSON. You can see 'script' tag in the logs.

I guess you are by mistake loading an html or some web url which returns html content to get JSON. Your server should return the JSON as plain text without html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Got your Problem You are not getting JSON response as response you are having all service in response see the first line of log cat.

Thats why you are unable to convert it to JSONObject. Edit your service and just return JSONObject from that.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your source code found some script and html. We strictly need "application/json" mimetype as a response from server.